# Connect to Azure machine via public ip from terraform

Tags: ubuntu, azure, cloud, packer, terraform

I successfull made the virtual machine in Azure with Terraform ( from a Packer image). After the Virtual machine created, I would run some commands remotely on the newly created machine.

The machine has a piblic ip but that ip attached dynamically to the new resource group what created by terrafrom. In this case I not know the puclic ip before the terraform starts.

Unfortunately the remote-exec provisioner needs an ip to connect for and ssh connect.
How can I solva that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two method could do this.

1.When you create VM, using DNS name. HOST is `<dns name>.<location>.cloudapp.azure.com`.

In tf file, Create public IP like below:

```
# create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ip" {
    name = "tfip"
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    domain_name_label = "sometestdn"

    tags {
        environment = "staging"
    }
}
```

Create connection like below:

```
   connection {
        host = "sometestdn.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com"
        user = "testuser"
        type = "ssh"
        private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa_unencrypted")}"
        timeout = "1m"
        agent = true
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "sudo apt-get update",
          "sudo apt-get install docker.io -y",
          "git clone https://github.com/somepublicrepo.git",
          "cd Docker-sample",
          "sudo docker build -t mywebapp .",
          "sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 mywebapp"
        ]
    }
```

2.Use [Azure Custom Script Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript).

> The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure
>   virtual machines. This extension is useful for post deployment
>   configuration, software installation, or any other configuration /
>   management task.

You could write your tf like below:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "helloterraformvm" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  location             = "West US"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.helloterraformvm.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions"
  type                 = "CustomScriptForLinux"
  type_handler_version = "1.2"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "apt-get install docker.io -y"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

More information please refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997257/ssh-connection-to-azure-vm-with-terraform/45002859).

Comment: Works. thank you. The "Terraform" label would very helpful in superuser.com

Comment: Ofcourse I do that